# High response times Parse Server Node express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, newrelic

I just set up a Heroku Standard Dyno connected to Mlab M1 dedicated cluster and am seeing high response times in New Relic for some calls. I need to know whats happen. Please Some and thanks[image]